# Getting custom claim value from bearer token (Web API)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, bearer-token

In my ASP.NET Web API project I'm using bearer token authorization and I have added some custom claims to it, like this:

```
var authType = AuthConfig.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType;
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(authType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, vm.Username));

// custom claim
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("CompanyID", profile.CompanyId.ToString()));
```

Is there any way I can access this additional claim value in the controller without an extra trip to the database?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Sure, inside your protected controller you do the following:

```
 ClaimsPrincipal principal = Request.GetRequestContext().Principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
 var customClaimValue = principal.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "CompanyID").Single().Value;
```

Comment: How could I reuse this in a more centralized manner? I am using a Service layer which needs i.e. this `customClaimValue`. All controller actions need to send this value to the service before getting/posting data.

Comment: You can create custom filter which runs before hitting your action method

Comment: Thanks, didn't know you could get the current request in a filter. Also a very nice blog you have there, Taiseer!

Comment: Personally, I do this in custom owin middleware early in the pipeline. Then I can access "CompanyID" from owin anywhere.

Comment: How can we do it when the OWIN server is in an WebAPI Project that we use to get authentication from a Web project ? I have that WebAPI that centralizes all business/authentication for all of our apps and i have a website that need control regulation and use the API to get the bearer token. But then i want to regulate access to controllers in website based on the token i received, which contains claims such as Role, companyID etc..